# javascript slider not slide automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create javascript slider with next and previous button.
Now next and previous button works fine.But alone with I need to slide automatically

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<body>
    <h2 class="slide">Manual Slideshow</h2>

    <div class="innerArea" style="max-width:800px;position:relative">
        <div class="SlidePic">
            <img class="" src="img_fjords.jpg" style="">
            <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
        <div class="SlidePic">
            <img src="image/oracle.png">
            <p>Hello1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="SlidePic">
            <img src="image/oracle.png">
            <p>Hello2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="SlidePic">
            <img src="img_forest.jpg">
            <p>Hello3</p>
        </div>

        <a class="w3-btn-floating" style="position:absolute;top:45%;left:0" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">></a>
        <a class="w3-btn-floating" style="position:absolute;top:45%;right:0" onclick="plusDivs(1)">
            <</a>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showDivs(slideIndex);

    function plusDivs(n) {
        showDivs(slideIndex += n);
    }
 function showDivs(n) {
  if(n=='')
  n=1; 
  var i;
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
 if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
 for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
 setTimeout(showDivs, 2000);
</script>
```

Comment: You are simply missing all *auto slider* logic. Use `setTimeout` or `setInterval` for that, but it's too broad for question and no one will write code for you

Comment: @ Justinas I 'll updated my code what I tried

Comment: You are not increasing slideIndex (check for boundaries to return to 0th element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML has images by class name 'SlidePic' and not 'mySlides'. Also stTimeOut function needs to be called from within the function that you repeatedly want to execute.  Hope this helps..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
    </head>


<body>
    <h2 class="slide">Manual Slideshow</h2>

    <div class="innerArea" style="max-width:800px;position:relative">
        <div class="SlidePic">
            <img class="" src="img_fjords.jpg" style="">
            <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
        <div class="SlidePic">
            <img src="image/oracle.png">
            <p>Hello1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="SlidePic">
            <img src="image/oracle.png">
            <p>Hello2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="SlidePic">
            <img src="img_forest.jpg">
            <p>Hello3</p>
        </div>

        <a class="w3-btn-floating" style="position:absolute;top:45%;right:0" onclick="plusDivs(0)">></a>
        <a class="w3-btn-floating" style="position:absolute;top:45%;left:0" onclick="plusDivs(-2)"><</a>

    </div>


<script>
    var slideIndex = 1;
   showDivs(slideIndex);

    function plusDivs(n) {
        slideIndex += n;
        showDivs();
    }
 function showDivs() {

  var n = slideIndex;
  // alert(n)  ;
  if(n==='' || n==='0' || n==="undefined")
  n=1; 
  var i;
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("SlidePic");
 if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
 if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
 for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
   slideIndex++;
  var t = setTimeout(function(){showDivs() }, 2000);
}


</script>

    </body>




</html>
```